# When I click on the button, the page is duplicated on itself

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I click on the button the counter advances correctly; but I get the unwelcome effect of duplicating the content of the page, what can I do? Thanks

I have a counter that takes the questions from a database, through Ajax I can increment the counter without refreshing the page:

```
<form action="prov1.php" name="forminvio" id="invio" method="get">
    <button type="button" name="segue" onclick="incrementa(o)"> + </button>
</form>

<div id="pulsant1"> <?php echo "Posizione  : " . $_GET['o'] . "<br>"; ?> </div>

<script>
    var o = <?php print $i; ?>;

    function domandaajax() {
         $.ajax({ // $.ajax è un metodo statico che ha la funzione di inviare richieste
         url: "prov1.php?o=" + o,  // url parametro di base ed è l’indirizzo al quale inviare la chiamata
         success:function(data) { // success, la funzione da lanciare se la richiesta ha successo
         document.getElementById("pulsant1").innerHTML = data;
      }
   });
}

// document.getElementById("pulsante").innerHTML = o; // scrive il primo valore di i nel paragrafo avente id pulsante

function incrementa() {
     //  document.getElementById("pulsante").innerHTML = o; // scrive l'incremento nel paragafo avente id pulsante
     o++;
     domandaajax();
     console.log(o);
}

</script>
```

[image: Before]
[image: after]

Comment: for me  this is the error even `prov1.php:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: incrementa is not defined`

Comment: what is the $i and are you using the two file like in one file this code written and second file is `prov1.php` or you are doing it all in one file `prov1.php'

Comment: $ i = 14; it is initialized this way, while the file is a unique one: prov1.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove content from your `div` first as below:

```
function domandaajax() {
    $.ajax({ // $.ajax è un metodo statico che ha la funzione di inviare richieste
    url: "prov1.php?o=" + o,  // url parametro di base ed è l’indirizzo al quale inviare la chiamata
      success:function(data) { // success, la funzione da lanciare se la richiesta ha successo
          document.getElementById("pulsant1").innerHTML = '';
          document.getElementById("pulsant1").innerHTML = data;
      }
   });
}
```

I hope it will work for you!!

Comment: don't work ... i always see prov1.php inside prov1.php